# How to access individual data points of MNIST data and check their size, shape etc from trainset object using torchvision's import dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist

the following code is

```
    from torchvision import datasets, transforms
    trainset = datasets.MNIST('./data/', download=True, train=True, transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))]))
```

I would like to visualize the first data point in the trainset variable above.
I want to have a look at the pixel values of the first data point by doing something like `print(trainset[0])` or check the size by doing `print(trainset[0].size)` or check the shape by doing `print(trainset[0].shape)` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For shape:

```
trainset.data.shape
```

```
torch.Size([60000, 28, 28])
```

For the first example:

```
trainset.data[0]
```

```
tensor([[[0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         ...,
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

To Visualize the data, you could plot it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(trainset.data[0], cmap='gray')
```

[image: plot of 1st image in the dataset]

To look at the pixel values of the 1st image:

```
print(trainset.data[0])
```

To find the shape of 1st image:

```
trainset.data[0].shape
>>>torch.Size([28, 28])
```

Instead of 0, you could replace it with any i, where i = size of the dataset

Comment: Thank you @Madhoolika